# current date in outlook subject line

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

How to have current date automaticlly added in the subject line of an email (template) in outlook 2010

for example

Todo for %mmm %d, %yyyy

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Outlook 2010 does not seem to have that built in. You would need to write a VBscript/macro to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can set an initial value of any field from the form design window.

1. Select the Subject field
2. RC / Properties
3. Click the "Value" tab
4. Check the "Set the initial value of this field to:"
5. Click the "Edit..." button next to the field
6. Type: "Todo for "& Date()

Or just check out the functions available to you.